# Can't open PDF from Servlet

Tags: servlets, itext

i trying to open a pdf right after i created.
I want to see the result in my browser, but i dosen't.
By the way, the programm runs on a server.
If i try to open the pdf there, no problem - all works fine.
Just the client can't see the pdf if he clicks, for example, on a button.

Here's my code:

```
@WebServlet("/GeneratePdfCustomer")
public class GeneratePdfCustomer extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    final int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    makePdf(request, response, "POST",id);

}

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
      }

 public void makePdf(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response, String methodGetPost, int id)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/pdf");


        try {

        Document document = new Document();         

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());

        document.open();

        document.add(new Paragraph("Test"));

        document.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Error" + e);
        }
      }
}
```

I using the **iText** library.

**EDIT:**

Now i have change my servlet code, but still not working for me.
I can't see the pdf in my browser. Firefox and IE both are show nothing.

```
package de.WorldCheckCustomer.model;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

@WebServlet("/GeneratePdfCustomer")
public class GeneratePdfCustomer extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    makePdf(request, response);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    makePdf(request, response);
}

public void makePdf(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    // Set content type to application / pdf
    // browser will open the document only if this is set
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    // Get the output stream for writing PDF object
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        /* Basic PDF Creation inside servlet */
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Tutorial to Generate PDF using    Servlet"));
        document.add(new Paragraph(
                "PDF Created Using Servlet, iText Example Works"));
        document.close();
    } catch (DocumentException exc) {
        throw new IOException(exc.getMessage());
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6067021675155015602L;

}
```

Comment: Have you tested on all browsers using different types of PDF viewers? What do you see in the browser? An error? A white page? Did you try the proof of concept from the book: http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/ Reading the book, you'll notice that you're very optimistic about the browser. Take a look at the [PdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173) from the book to find out what is different.

Comment: @Lowagie Nothing happens, no blank page, no error in the IDE. But if i change the PdfWriter Instance to a final place in a folder, and the client clicked on the button to generate a pdf, the file is stored into this folder. So the only think that dosen't work, is to show the page immediately.

Comment: You have established that the problem is not caused by iText (if it were, then the PDF created with the change `PdfWriter` would be wrong too). What happens if you test the Servlet from my book: http://itextpdf.com:8180/book/

Comment: It works normally POST and the GET Method

Comment: That proves that your problem is caused by ignoring the documentation. Adapt your Servlet as instructed (and shown in [PdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173)) and your problem will disappear.